# Dolphin Browser not showing File transfer Progress

Tags: 18.04, transfer, dolphin

I like dolphin browser over nautilus browser, only problem I can't enable file progress in Ubuntu 18.04,file transfer is working but not showing progress is it a bug or something messing with settings ?